# color cells when value appears also in other colum

Tags: excel

I have two colums:

```
C1   C2
1   2
2   5
3   6
4   8
5   10
6   15
```

I want all the cells from C1 with a value that also appears in C2 to be highlighted. In reverse I also want the cells from C2 with a value that also appears in C1 to be highlighted.

I tried to use conditional formatting with a VLOOKUP formula, but probably i'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the following formulas as conditional formatting rules:

1. Column A: select entire column and apply the following as condition: `=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0))`
2. Column B: select entire column and apply the following as condition: `=ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0))`

Select desired highlight and you're done.

Sample file with your data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8yod11xd4qyr0i/Highlight2Columns.xlsx

Comment: Plenty of otimization potential here:1.Better use `MATCH` then `VLOOKUP` as your vlookup just imitates the match 2. No need for `IF(...,0,1)=1` - this will return exactly the same result as the condition in the if. Therefore, all you need is `=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0))`

Comment: And another small comment: You're using ';` as your local separator (same for me), while the majority of users uses the English local `,`. What usually do to convert the formula is to select the cell and the execute `? Selection.Formula` in the Immediate window of VBE. :-)

Comment: @PeterAlbert thanks for the trick))) Updated the answer with `,` - sorry for the confusion, mostly I don't forget to do that.